# How to listen to Connection Abort event in Apache MINA SSHD SFTP server?

Tags: java, sftp, apache-sshd

I have setup SFTPGateway using Apache MINA SSHD version 2.1.0. After User authentication and establishing the connection, I want to capture/listen to the Connection Abort event (by pressing Ctrl+C) while performing PUT operation. Can someone kindly help me on this?

I tried overriding public void closed(ServerSession serverSession, String remoteHandle, Handle localHandle, Throwable thrown) method in AbstractSftpEventListenerAdapter class. But its called not only when file is completely uploaded and closed for IO operation but also when Connection is aborted even before File is fully uploaded. So I couldn't rely on this method for file upload completion.

The ask is to trigger some action after file upload is fully completed not when Connection is aborted during PUT operation and the file upload is not 100% completed. So how do I capture file upload completion in Apache MINA SSHD server?

I believe earlier there was an Interface FileUploadAware in earlier version 0.13 and 0.14 which serves the purpose.

```
public class MySFTPEventListener extends AbstractSftpEventListenerAdapter {
.....
....
@Override
    public void closed(ServerSession serverSession, String remoteHandle, Handle localHandle, Throwable thrown) {
        File closedFile = localHandle.getFile().toFile();
        log.info(String.format("User %s closed file: %s with Active session %d", serverSession.getUsername(),
                closedFile.getAbsolutePath(), serverSession.getActiveSessionCountForUser(serverSession.getUsername())));
    }
}
```

How can I listen to Connection Abort event in Apache SSHD SFTP during PUT (Upload) operation?

Comment: *"But its called even when Connection is aborted before File is fully uploaded"* – That's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: SSHD 2.3 added this new feature: `The user can use a registered SessionDisconnectHandler in order be informed and also intervene in cases where the code decides to disconnect the session due to various protocol or configuration parameters violations.` ([Source](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/changes/2.3.0.md)) Not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Roman for your input. I have edited my post and added few details and my ask. Can you please suggest your input?